# Is there anyway to code such that I can define or condition in middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have three roles in my application. I have a condition in which two roles can access same page. For that I write below code.

in below code, sub plan1 and sub plan 2 are roles.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth', 'SubPlan1', 'SubPlan2']], function () {
    Route::get('/Parent-1-Info', '\ContactInfoController@Parent1Info'));
});
```

if sub plan1, tries to access the page, I get 404 error because i mentioned both middleware in same group.

Is there anyway to code such that I can define or condition in middleware?

Comment: you could always make a middleware that takes parameters, then pass the 'roles' as the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For role based authentication I'm using this middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;
use Closure;
use App\Role;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class RoleMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $roles = null, $guard = null)
    {
        $roles = Role::whereIn('slug', explode('|', $roles))->get();

        if (! Auth::guard($guard)->user()->hasRole($roles)) {
            return abort(403, 'Forbidden');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then register the middleware in `Kernel.php`

```
'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
```

On the user model make sure you have a method to check if user has a set of roles, example:

```
public function hasRole($role)
{
    if (is_int($role)) {
        return $this->roles->contains('id', $role);
    }

    if (is_string($role)) {
        return $this->roles->contains('slug', $role);
    }

    if ($role instanceof Model) {
        return $this->roles->contains('id', $role->id);
    }

    return !! $role->intersect($this->roles)->count();
}
```

And you can use the middleware like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:admin|staff'], ...);
```

You can replace `admin|staff` with your role names, separated by `|`. If you want to add custom `guard` then you can pass it as second parameter `role:admin|staff,mycustomguard`